# Primefaces p:fileUpload add onClick functionality

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

I want to start `p:poll` when user click on upload button on `p:fileUpload`

***NOTE:*** when i put manually `onclick` script into the button using browser elements works fine. i want to do that same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when the user clicks on the upload button the `onstart` event is fired so you can use it.

```xhtml
<p:fileUpload onstart="PF('pollWV').start()" />
```